# Is "check out" naturally used to mean "see"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

A: Why did you come?

B: I just wanted to **check out** your paintings.

A has mentioned to B that A paints a lot, so B is interested to finally see A's paintings. Is **check out** natural here to mean "see"? Is it very informal or perfectly natural?

Answer (score 5):

"Check out" means to intentionally investigate something, to evaluate or otherwise come to a conclusion about it.  It does not require seeing, though in this case, you would have to because you can't evaluate paintings by other means.  You would check out a restaurant to see whether it was any good before you invited friends there.  You would check out a prospective employee to see if he lied on his resume.

Conversely, you can see something without checking it out.  A janitor who came to the room to clean up a mess would see any paintings in it, but would not necessarily check them out.

Comment: seems a good distinction you made there

Comment: Good answer.  One thing you didn't address was the OP's question of whether it was an informal usage.  In my view, it's slightly informal.

Comment: 'Check out' is still mainly American.

Comment: Not to be confused with the act of borrowing a library book, departing a hotel, or code repository operations.  @MichaelHarvey I would suggest 'western', I think this is a fairly well-known idiom throughout CA, UK, AU, NZ, even western Euro.

Comment: It is stil an Americanism, even if it is well known.